# Guard specs do not run automatically when watched files are changed

Tags: nitrousio

My `guardfile` is setup properly and guard runs fine, but I have to manually trigger the tests every time I want them to run. The whole purpose of guard is that it is supposed to monitor your files and run your tests any time they change. I don't know if there is something wrong with the Nitrous.io environment or my settings.

If you need more information just ask and I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guard supports polling, please try to launch guard with `bundle exec guard -p`.

Comment: This works great! I should have looked through the Guard documentation before asking the question...

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE SEPT 2nd 2013**

We recently updated the filesystem on any new boxes, so inotify is now supported.  Your build scripts using fsmonitor should work correctly on any new boxes you create.

We'll be adding your box's version number in the boxes index page.  Boxes in Version2 and later will be using the new filesystem and will support inotify.

Comment: Interestingly enough, creating a new file that fits the `watch` settings triggers the tests, though saving changes to the file does not trigger it again.